# Angular acceleration as a function of angular velocity squared and angular displacement?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-velocity

I was reading [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-displaystyle-frac-d-2-theta-dt-2-+-frac-g-L-sin-theta-0-to-form-the-pendulum-equation-T-2-pi-sqrt-L-g) on Quora which stated that angular acceleration $\alpha$ can be expressed as $ - \omega^2 \theta $ where $\omega$ is angular velocity and $\theta$ is the angular displacement. I’ve found no way of proving such statement, in fact, I believe it’s wrong (the units don’t even match) unless of course it’s a special case for the pendulum which is what the question on Quora is about.

So, could someone help me understand why $ \alpha = - \omega^2 \theta $ if that is even true.

Thanks

Comment: $\omega$ isn't an angular velocity in this context